# SE sites link to StackOverflow's FAQ?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, hyperlinks, stackexchange-2.0

On the [Featured Questions page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), when there are no bounties the link points the user to [StackOverflow's FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) instead of [Gaming's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty).

---

**EDIT**: I just reproduced this on Math SE so I'm assuming it does it on every site.

Comment: Reproduced on the [DIY beta](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=featured), so it's not just fully-fledged sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops, typo. Fixed.